# i can't write path of folder DirectorySeparatorChar dosen't work

Tags: c#, .net-core

i try to write path of folder but all of the way i write give '//' not '/'

```
   string path = "C:\\Users\\AVITAL\\Desktop\\my-first-project\\src\\assets\\image\\";
   f= Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
   string path = "C:{f}Users{f}AVITAL{f}Desktop{f}my-first-project{f}src{f}assets{f}image{f}";
   string path = "@C:\Users\AVITAL\Desktop\my-first-project\src\assets\image\";
```

all this ways give me this exeption:

{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\AVITAL\Desktop\my-first-project\src\assets\image\83182021-07-19.jpg'."}

i want to get file from angular and save it in assets folder

```
    public async Task<bool> addNewcustomerImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {


            string end = file.FileName;

            string path = "C:\\Users\\AVITAL\\Desktop\\my-first-project\\src\\assets\\image\\";

            string finalPath = path + end;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(finalPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

          {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

i think the problem in my computer because it work on my lase computer

Comment: You need to prefix the string literal with `$` to use interpolated strings `{` `}`.

Comment: Also, in practice, you don't need to use `DirectorySeparatorChar` because all OSes that run .NET (Windows, macOS, Linux, etc) all support using a forward-slash as a separator.

Comment: Also, the idiomatic approach is to use `Path.Combine()` which has a variadic `params String[]` parameter.

Comment: i use $ i forget write this

Comment: but i get 92 '//'

Comment: Please share a screenshot of a command prompt with `C:\Users\AVITAL\Desktop\my-first-project\src\assets\image` as the active directory.

Comment: `C:\Users\AVITAL\Desktop\my-first-project\src\assets\image` has to exist for this to work. Use `Directory.Create()` if it does not.

Comment: "i use $ i forget write this" - you should then [edit] your question accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way of solving your problem is using `Path.Combine()`

Comment: You can write an exenple because i try this way but it dosen't work

Answer (score -1):

Try using the @ symbol so that you don't have to escape any character in a string.

```
string end = file.FileName;
string path = @"C:\Users\AVITAL\Desktop\my-first-project\src\assets\image\";
string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path,end);
```

Comment: No; use path.combine instead so that paths are built in a way that respects the directory separator char of the host environment; .net is not the Windows-only shop it once was

Comment: @CaiusJard Windows supports forward-slashes in paths and has done for decades. Using `Path.Combine` results in unnecessary string allocations.

Comment: My comment was exactly *not* about Windows though..